# App Engine vs Compute Engine as simple API to Memorystore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm setting up a database that will just store basic information about items in an economy such as their sellers (price and seller id), recent average price, and past sales.

My game servers will be interacting with and operating on this data. I don't expect it to take more than 1 GB in size, so I want to just store it on one Redis server.

*The problem is*, I'm not sure if I should use App Engine and **potentially have multiple instances**, or **just one Compute Engine instance** (if it were a Compute Engine instance, I wouldn't have a separate Redis server because the code isn't very computationally expensive).

Right now I am thinking that because there is only one Redis server (since I'm not doing sharding), if there were multiple instances through the App Engine, everything would still be throttled by the Redis server. Notwithstanding this, are external web requests much more expensive than the internal ones in Google's network? If so, would App Engine be necessary?

Comment: Cloud Memorystore is so fast compared to the CPU speed of App Engine. You could have dozens of instances talking to Memorystore without any problem. In order to overwhelm Memorystore you would need to generate hundreds/thousands of requests per second. App Engine can scale big, but then your design is in a different ballpark with a new set of considerations (pricing, fault tolerance for Memorystore, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the architecture for the App, App Engine, is ready for High-Performance, if you are interested in the resilient and the scalability, is a good choice, the horizontal scalability allows you the advantage of give you as  many instances as you need.
A difference between the Compute Engine and App Engine could be the App Engine is ready for the Code, and let you choose between many programming languages.
The Compute Engine gives you the facility to choose the booth image, between a variety according to your specifications.